# How to config nginx to request multiples microservices on node

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, microservices

I'm trying to configure nginx to manage all request and redirect to proper microservice on node/express. All microservices works fine, connecting to Redis and Postgres.

I would like to manage without use ports on URL something like...

- http://localhost/auth (dockerized microservice 1)
- http://localhost/banks (dockerized microservice 2)
- http://localhost/users (dockerized microservice 3)

I'm currently using Docker with multiples images, here's most relevant files..

Any idea? Thanks!

docker-compose.yml

`version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        links:
            - auth:auth
            - banks:banks
            - users:users
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    amplify:
        build: ./docker-nginx-amplify
        environment:
            - API_KEY=
            - AMPLIFY_IMAGENAME=development
    auth:
        build: ./api-auth
        environment:
            - PG_SERVER=172.19.0.3
        links:
            - redis
            - postgres
            - banks
        ports:
            - "8888"
    banks:
        build: ./api-banks
        environment:
            - PG_SERVER=172.19.0.3
        links:
            - redis
            - postgres
        ports:
            - "8888"
    users:
        build: ./api-users
        environment:
            - PG_SERVER=172.19.0.3
        links:
            - redis
            - postgres
        ports:
            - "8888"
    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
            - "6379"
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        hostname: postgres
        ports:
        - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgresuser
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgresuser
            POSTGRES_DB: privatedatabase
        restart: unless-stopped`

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 4;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
    upstream node-app {
        least_conn;
        server auth:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        server banks:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
       server users:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;


location / {
        proxy_pass http://node-app;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I replaced this setup with Traefik. Cheers!